# Python -need help understanding the difference between these two pieces of code

Tags: python, loops, tuples, nltk

Is there any difference between the following two pieces of code:

```
distances = ((jaccard_distance(set(nltk.ngrams(entry, gram_number)),
                                   set(nltk.ngrams(word,    gram_number))), word)
                for word in spellings)
```

and

```
for word in spellings:
    distances = ((jaccard_distance(set(nltk.ngrams(entry, gram_number)),
                                   set(nltk.ngrams(word,    gram_number))), word))
```

What exactly is the difference? Thanks in advance for helping out

Comment: "Is there any difference ..." You mean you never tried to run the two snippets and inspect `distances`?

Answer (score 4):

Getting the Jaccard distance between 2 bag of words, i.e. unique vocabulary of 2 sentences.

```
>>> from nltk.metrics import jaccard_distance
>>> from nltk import ngrams

>>> sent1 = "This is a foo bar sentence".split()
>>> sent2 = "A bar bar black sheep have you a sentence".split()

>>> set(sent1) # A list of unique words in sent1
set(['a', 'bar', 'sentence', 'This', 'is', 'foo'])
>>> set(sent2) # A list of unique words in sent2
set(['A', 'sheep', 'bar', 'sentence', 'black', 'a', 'have', 'you'])

>>> jaccard_distance(set(sent1), set(sent2))
0.7272727272727273
```

Now if it's bag of ngrams:

```
>>> list(ngrams(sent2, 3)) # list of tri-grams in sent2.
[('A', 'bar', 'bar'), ('bar', 'bar', 'black'), ('bar', 'black', 'sheep'), ('black', 'sheep', 'have'), ('sheep', 'have', 'you'), ('have', 'you', 'a'), ('you', 'a', 'sentence')]

>>> set(list(ngrams(sent2, 3))) # unique set of tri-grams in sent2.
set([('A', 'bar', 'bar'), ('have', 'you', 'a'), ('you', 'a', 'sentence'), ('sheep', 'have', 'you'), ('black', 'sheep', 'have'), ('bar', 'black', 'sheep'), ('bar', 'bar', 'black')])


>>> set(ngrams(sent2, 3))
set([('A', 'bar', 'bar'), ('have', 'you', 'a'), ('you', 'a', 'sentence'), ('sheep', 'have', 'you'), ('black', 'sheep', 'have'), ('bar', 'black', 'sheep'), ('bar', 'bar', 'black')])

>>> set(ngrams(sent1, 3))
set([('This', 'is', 'a'), ('a', 'foo', 'bar'), ('is', 'a', 'foo'), ('foo', 'bar', 'sentence')])

>>> jaccard_distance(set(ngrams(sent1,3)), set(ngrams(sent2, 3)))
1.0
```

---

**What does Jaccard distance of 1.0 mean?**

It means the 2 sequences in comparison are totally different, in this case the unique set of ngrams from each sentence.

---

Previously, we had a sentence string split into list of strings and when we compare 2 sequences, they are comparing the words/ngrams in the sentences.

Now if we iterate 2 words instead of sentences, we are splitting the words into a list of characters, i.e.

```
>>> word1 = 'Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'
>>> word2 = 'Honorificabilitudinitatibus'

>>> list(word1) # The list of characters in the word
['S', 'u', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's']

>>> set(list(word1)) # The set of unique characters in the word
set(['a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 's', 'l', 'o', 'p', 'S', 'r', 'u', 't', 'x'])

>>> set(ngrams(word1, 3)) # The set of unique character trigrams in the word.
set([('c', 'a', 'l'), ('S', 'u', 'p'), ('t', 'i', 'c'), ('d', 'o', 'c'), ('f', 'r', 'a'), ('i', 'f', 'r'), ('r', 'a', 'g'), ('i', 's', 't'), ('s', 't', 'i'), ('x', 'p', 'i'), ('u', 'p', 'e'), ('o', 'u', 's'), ('i', 'c', 'e'), ('l', 'i', 'f'), ('p', 'e', 'r'), ('o', 'c', 'i'), ('g', 'i', 'l'), ('l', 'i', 'd'), ('i', 'l', 'i'), ('c', 'i', 'o'), ('r', 'c', 'a'), ('l', 'i', 's'), ('a', 'g', 'i'), ('p', 'i', 'a'), ('i', 'o', 'u'), ('e', 'x', 'p'), ('i', 'a', 'l'), ('c', 'e', 'x'), ('a', 'l', 'i'), ('i', 'd', 'o'), ('e', 'r', 'c')])
```

And to get the Jaccard distance between them:

```
>>> jaccard_distance(set(ngrams(word1, 3)), set(ngrams(word2, 3)))
0.9818181818181818
```

---

Now to the OP's question:

```
distances = ((jaccard_distance(set(nltk.ngrams(entry, gram_number)),
                               set(nltk.ngrams(word,    gram_number))), word)
            for word in spellings)
```

vs

```
for word in spellings:
    distances = ((jaccard_distance(set(nltk.ngrams(entry, gram_number)),
                               set(nltk.ngrams(word,    gram_number))), word))
```

The first thing that you can try to do is to simplify the code:

- Use namespaces, they're your friends
- Use functions if you have to retype the same thing again and again.
- Use explicit and clear variable names

---

## Using namespaces

Instead of typing `nltk.ngrams(...)` again and again, you can do this:

```
>>> from nltk import ngrams
>>> list(ngrams('foobar', 3))
[('f', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'b'), ('o', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'r')]
```

And if you're specifically using only n-gram order of 2 or 3, i.e. bigrams or trigrams, you can do:

```
>>> from nltk import bigrams, trigrams
>>> list(bigrams('foobar'))
[('f', 'o'), ('o', 'o'), ('o', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'r')]
>>> list(trigrams('foobar'))
[('f', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'b'), ('o', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'r')]
```

And if you want to get fancy and make a customized function for your desired order of ngrams, you can try `functools.partial`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from nltk import ngrams

>>> octagram = partial(ngrams, n=8)

>>> word = 'Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'
>>> octagram(word)
<generator object ngrams at 0x10cafff00>

>>> list(octagram(word))
[('S', 'u', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l'), ('u', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i'), ('p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f'), ('e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r'), ('r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g'), ('a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i'), ('l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l'), ('i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i'), ('f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's'), ('r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't'), ('a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i'), ('g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c'), ('i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e'), ('l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x'), ('i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p'), ('s', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i'), ('t', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a'), ('i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l'), ('c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i'), ('e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd'), ('x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o'), ('p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c'), ('i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i'), ('a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o'), ('l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'u'), ('i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's')]
```

---

## Using functions

Instead of re-writing the `set(nltk.ngrams(word, gram_number))`, you get `uco(word)`:

```
>>> from nltk import ngrams
>>> def unique_character_octagrams(text, n=8):
...     return set(ngrams(text, n))
... 
>>> uco = unique_character_octagrams
>>> uco(word1)
set([('e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd'), ('S', 'u', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l'), ('i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l'), ('a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i'), ('t', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a'), ('i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e'), ('i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's'), ('c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i'), ('l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x'), ('f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's'), ('l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l'), ('i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i'), ('p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c'), ('a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'i'), ('x', 'p', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o'), ('e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r'), ('l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o', 'u'), ('g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c'), ('i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p'), ('r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a'), ('r', 'a', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'i', 's', 't'), ('i', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i'), ('p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f'), ('a', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'o'), ('u', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'i'), ('c', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'g'), ('s', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'x', 'p', 'i')])
```

---

## Use Explicit + Clear Variable Names

In the OP, you've used `for word in spellings` to iterate the spellings and it's unclear what's `spellings`. It'll be best if you have a sample input of `spellings` in the OP so that answerers don't need to guess in the dark what exactly is `spellings`.

From the looping and Jaccard distance usage, it looks like `spellings` is a list of words, so a better variable name would be `list_of_words` and the iteration would be clearer without comments, e.g. `for word in list_of_words`.

In addition, the `entry` variable is also ambiguous and from the usage, it's most probably a query that you want to perform on the list of words, so a possible variable name is `query_word`.

```
def unique_character_trigrams(text, n=3):
    return set(ngrams(text, n))

uct = unique_character_trigrams

list_of_words = ['Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 'Honorificabilitudinitatibus']

query_word = 'Antidisestablishmentarianism'

for word in list_of_words:
    d = jaccard_distance(uct(query_word), uct(word))
    print("Comparing {} vs {}\nJaccard = {}\n".format(query_word, word, d))
```

[out]:

```
Comparing Antidisestablishmentarianism vs Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
Jaccard = 0.982142857143

Comparing Antidisestablishmentarianism vs Honorificabilitudinitatibus
Jaccard = 1.0
```

---

Now, really going back to the OP question. Let's treat :

- `spelling` as `x`, i.e. a list of numbers
- `entry` as `y`, i.e. a static number
- `word` as `num`, i.e. a number from the list of numbers
- `jaccard_distance` as `f`, a simple subtraction function.

If the first scenario, this syntax of looping a sequence inline is [list comprehension](https://www.google.com/search?q=list%20comprehension). The output is a generator type and you have to materialize the generator with `list` and inside the generator, each element is the output from `f`:

```
>>> x = [10, 20, 30] # A list of numbers. 
>>> y = 3 # A number to compare against the list.
>>> f = lambda x, y: x - y # A simple function to do x - y
>>> f(10,3)
7
>>> f(20,3)
17
>>> result = (f(num,y) for num in x)
>>> result
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10cafff00>
>>> list(result)
[7, 17, 27]
```

In the second scenario, it's the more traditional way of iterating,you get a single integer output in each iteration of the loop:

```
>>> for num in x:
...     result = f(num, y)
...     print(type(result), result)
... 
(<type 'int'>, 7)
(<type 'int'>, 17)
(<type 'int'>, 27)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. I am new here . Going forward I will make sure my posts are more explanatory . While your write up cleared up quite a few things , I still had one more question. I used the "minimum" to find the word with the minimum Jaccard distance on the results of the list generated by both loops . The results were different . Shouldn't they be the same ?

Comment: Ask another question or modify your question to add the details of how you use the resulting list ;P

Answer (score 0):

In **case 1**:

The distances is a tuple and contains the values for all words in spellings
such as:

```
(0.1111111111111111, 'hello')

(0.2222222222222222, 'world')

(0.5, 'program')

(0.2727272727272727, 'computer')

(0.0, 'spell')
```

In **case 2**:

The distances get overwritten so distances will contain only last value

```
(0.0, 'spell')
```

Comment: In the first case `distances` is actually a generator for the tuples you described